# Stimulant which kills the user in the absence of strenuous physical activity

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, medicine

I recently had an idea for a sci-fi story about death's row inmates (possibly war criminals) being subjected to an experimental stimulant which greatly increases their strength and agility, but will cause their hearts to burst in the absence of strenuous physical activity (as in it kills them as a natural side effect, rather than an artificial "kill switch".) Would such a stimulant be scientifically feasible, in theory?

Comment: Well, sugar does that, it just takes years to do so.

Comment: Isn't this basically the premise of the movie [Crank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank_(film))?

Comment: Put experimental on that. You're basically telling us that if they sleep or simply rest (the things you do which usually help you staying **sane** and allow you to repair your muscles after using them too much) they will die, aka you're just executing them in a  much less humane way, all while letting them know they have to choose between dying now or dying after they torn their own muscles apart from overexertion in a pointless attempt to somewhat extend their lifespan.

Comment: @ProjectApex Does depend on how long the effect lasts.

Answer (score 8):

It's something plausible if the molecule of the stimulant has a steric conformation such that it act as a stimulant, because it binds to the relative receptors, and also is strongly similar to glycogen, so that muscles use it as energy source.

Because of the above properties, intense physical activity consumes the molecule and therefore lowers its hematic concentration below the lethal dose. Lacking the consumption due to physical activity the over excitation of the organism will kill it due to the lack of rest.

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't be a stimulant, but a relaxant that would cause the heart to stop beating if not made to pump by activity. The slowdown of heartrate would have to be a side effect of something else though, as there's no reason to just slowdown one's heartrate.